# Improve adjustability of gas stove

Tags: gas, stove

I've got a gas hob (valberg brand) running on a cylinder. The problem is that it has virtually no adjustability - when I turn the knob to make the flame smallest it barely reduces the flame at all. So it is impossible to simmer.

Is there a way to improve the range from biggest to smallest flame? I appreciate it is probably different for every hob, but maybe there are some generalities.

Comment: Is this a single burner or multiple?  If multiple, do all the burners do the same thing?  Is your gas pressure where it should be for this stove?  Do you have a pressure regulator and is it set and working properly?

Comment: Did it ever work differently or is this a brand-new installation?

Comment: @jwh20 It has 2 burners, one big one small. As far as I know there is no pressure regulator, unless there is one incorporated into the stove.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft It has always been like this, I know a hack to get the flame down but my other half won't accept it any longer.

Comment: Simmer your saucepan on top of a larger cast-iron skillet. Like a double-boiler w/o the boil. If still too hot, add some pennies between the pans to reduce thermal contact. You can also choke it off at the tank by turning the knob almost off; I once had to do that on a friend's BBQ to get it low and slow for some thick chops; worked perfect.

Answer (score 5):

Propane and Natural Gas Are Supplied at Different Pressures

A propane stove orifice size is about 0.082 inches (drill size 45), but the valve on a similar stove that uses natural gas needs an orifice that is almost 0.125 inches (drill size 35).

If you are running your range from propane but using the orifice for natural gas, you will get this behaviour.  You may need to buy or install the correct orifice for propane.

Comment: Thanks I will look into this.

Comment: Also a regulator should be in place where cylinder attached to the    unit. Typically these can be set for propane( LPG) or natural gas.

Comment: Depending on location (probably not the US) bottle gas can also be butane (and perhaps others?) Assuming "bottle gas for home cooking == LPG" is not applicable worldwide.

Comment: Yes indeed it is butane. I have ordered some injectors of different sizes so hopefully something will work.

Answer (score 4):

Check the manual for the hob *(range/stovetop/pick a word that works based on where you live - for the OP, hob it is.)*

The last such manual I read (while checking a similar problem) the regulator was in the correct position (convertible between LP/Natural Gas) but there was also supposed to be an adjustment for the lowest flame on each burner.

I say "supposed to be" because the combination of "tiny screw deep inside the stem of the control knob" and "not easily turned" meant none of my collection of screwdrivers could do the job, so I gave up (rental, short-term, not worth the bother.) But you might have such a thing available (may not be the same location, which is why you want to check the manual for details applicable to your specific hob.)

Comment: Roy Scheider voice: "You're gonna need a bigger .... collection of screwdrivers!"   :-)